# Displaying my database in html

Tags: html, mysql, sql, database, razor

My database is called: **Baseball** and the table i want to display is called: **Players**.

I made a database that has different baseball teams and different players from baseball teams.

For example in my Teams table the team name "Red Sox" has a teamID '2' that primary key is linked to the Players table under "team". Now I have a few players with '2' as their team.

I created a html file and want to display only the Players with 2 as the data shown under team.

Here is the code I have so far I keep messing with it. I finally got this which gives me no errors however I don't know how to write a function that displays it.

```
@{  
    var db = Database.Open("Baseball");
    var selectQueryString = @"SELECT firstname , lastname  FROM Players WHERE team = 2";    
}
```

Comment: What language and/or framework are you using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Baseball");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Players WHERE team = 2";
 }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <table>
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>First Name </th>
               <th>Last Name </th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){
            <tr>
               <td>@row.firstname</td>
               <td>@row.lastname</td>
            </tr>
           }
       </tbody>
   </table>
 </body>
</html>
```